# Figuring out Spring Logging

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I've inherited a, well, messy, Spring MVC application. Some things don't work and I want to enable DEBUG or even TRACE logging to get more information and found that even that is not that simple.

When starting the application (by running a Tomcat 8 server from Eclipse), it seems to output two kinds of log messages. Here is an example of the first kind:

```
Jun 20, 2017 1:47:07 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO:
HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final} Jun 20, 2017 1:47:07 PM
org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit> INFO: HHH000206:
hibernate.properties not found Jun 20, 2017 1:47:07 PM
org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider INFO: HHH000021:
Bytecode provider name : javassist
```

These messages are all in red. The second kind looks like this:

```
13:47:16.949 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:489 - FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
13:47:16.952 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext:583 - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Tue Jun 20 13:47:16 IDT 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
13:47:16.952 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
```

These are all in black.

Obviously there are at least two active logging formats. This is were it gets weird:

I found numerous `log4j2.xml` as well as `log4j.properties`files. All of them seem to be ignored. Changing them makes no difference. I just deleted them all, and it did not affect the logging output. In addition, log4j 1.2, log4j 2.0.2 and slf4j are all Maven dependencies. `pom.xml` references version 1.2, other Maven dependencies probably need the other versions.

My question is - how do I configure the logging myself? Placing a log4j.xml file under WEB-INF (were all other property files are located) doesn't make any difference. Neither that placing a log4j.properties file there. I need to somehow turn debug printouts of log4j itself, so I can figure out where it's reading it's configuration from.

I tried adding `-Dlog4j.debug` as a VM argument to the Tomcat run configuarion. Other than printing `-Dlog4j.debug command line argument` or something similar, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet that I have used for my project. Over here class name is FolderReader.class and  placed lo4j.properties file in folder "conf".Passing argument "../conf/log4j.properties"  as args[2] argument when running the application.

```
final FileSystemXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(args[0]);
    Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(FolderReader.class);
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(args[2]);
    logger.info("Intializing beans..");
    ServiceContext serviceContext = (ServiceContext) BeanFactoryLocator.getBean("serviceContext");
```

PropertyConfigurator.configure(args[2]);loads the log4j.properties file from location. Configuration is taken from this property file and formatting is done accordingly.